# Do graphical control elements have a standard naming in Gnome?

Tags: linux, gnome

So I need to know if there are standard names of [widgets (graphical control elements)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_%28GUI%29).
For example the wikipedia article for [Drop-down list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-down_list) reads:

> A drop-down menu (also drop down menu or drop-down list or drop menu
>   or pull-down list or simply a drop down)[...]

So there are many names by wich Drop-down list may appear in bug reports or in help documentation. This makes it harder to search for a particular bug for this element.

I need to know if Linux follows a standard naming convention, or at least if the desktop environment Gnome follows one (the one wich I'm having problems with).

Answer (score 1):

There is a gallery for [Gtk+](http://www.gtk.org/) widgets in the following link:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch03.html

You can also access the documentation by clicking on each image.

Hope this helps!